# How to replace missing data in one column from a duplicate row

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, missing-data

Here is a sample of data the data set is large and I want to be able to replace all missing values with the correct value based on if the value in the ID column is equal.

```
Id.data<-data.frame(
  ID = c(564,758,987,1568,4987,413578,987,65647,4895,564,135,1568),
  gender= c("male","female","female","male","male","female","female","male", "female","male","male","male"),
  race= c ("Caucasian","Black","Caucasion","Hispanic","Hispanic","Asian","NA","BLack","Black","NA","Asian","NA"),
  Hours = c(45,54,32,24,56,40,42,25,40,36,56,24),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Comment: In your sample data the missing race values are strings, `"NA"`, not missing values `NA`. Is that the case in your real data, or are the quotes around `"NA"` typos?

Comment: Thank you I will fix that the missing data though is not NA it is a character string "missing"  I used "NA" because I would have to convert it to NA first correct? Before I could replace the values.

Comment: Yeah, as I say in my answer you want it to be `NA` and the easiest place to fix that is when your data is imported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your missing values are `NA`, not `"NA"`, we can use `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
Id.data %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  fill(everything(), .direction = "downup")
```

If your missing values have quotes, that is a problem that is better solved upstream in your workflow - if you show us the code for when those values are created/imported we can help you create them properly.

Comment: I am wondering why you decided to use `complete` instead of `fill(race, .direction = "downup")`

Comment: Silly typo, misremembering the correct function name.

Comment: would you also group race with ID?

Comment: @jdd117 No! Operations happen **within groups**. If you group by both ID and race, then you'll only have one race value within a group, there won't be any new information to fill with.

Comment: Yep so right. I just had to add "arrange(ID)%>%" after group_by to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that your data set was large. It might be worthwhile considering a `data.table` approach.

```r
Id.data<-data.frame( ID = c(564,758,987,1568,4987,413578,987,65647,4895,564,135,1568), gender= c("male","female","female","male","male","female","female","male", "female","male","male","male"), race= c ("Caucasian","Black","Caucasion","Hispanic","Hispanic","Asian",NA,"BLack","Black",NA,"Asian",NA), Hours = c(45,54,32,24,56,40,42,25,40,36,56,24), stringsAsFactors = FALSE )

dt <- as.data.table(Id.data)

dt[, lapply( .SD, function(v)na.locf(v, fromLast=TRUE) ), by=ID ]
```

Output:

```
        ID gender      race Hours
 1:    564   male Caucasian    45
 2:    564   male Caucasian    36
 3:    758 female     Black    54
 4:    987 female Caucasion    32
 5:    987 female Caucasion    42
 6:   1568   male  Hispanic    24
 7:   1568   male  Hispanic    24
 8:   4987   male  Hispanic    56
 9: 413578 female     Asian    40
10:  65647   male     BLack    25
11:   4895 female     Black    40
12:    135   male     Asian    56
```

And timing the two approaches:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(microbenchmark)
library(data.table)

Id.data<-data.frame( ID = c(564,758,987,1568,4987,413578,987,65647,4895,564,135,1568), gender= c("male","female","female","male","male","female","female","male", "female","male","male","male"), race= c ("Caucasian","Black","Caucasion","Hispanic","Hispanic","Asian",NA,"BLack","Black",NA,"Asian",NA), Hours = c(45,54,32,24,56,40,42,25,40,36,56,24), stringsAsFactors = FALSE )

dt <- as.data.table(Id.data)

dt[, lapply( .SD, function(v)na.locf(v, fromLast=TRUE) ), by=ID ]

microbenchmark(
    dplyr = Id.data %>% group_by(ID) %>% fill(everything(), .direction = "downup"),
    dt = dt[, lapply( .SD, function(v)na.locf(v, fromLast=TRUE) ), by=ID ]
)
```

benchmark table:

```
Unit: milliseconds
  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval cld
 dplyr 4.397308 4.493263 4.684294 4.552560 4.639137  9.966245   100   b
    dt 1.238002 1.270062 1.421998 1.303184 1.330787 12.470191   100  a
```

Roughly 3.5 times faster with data.table.